# TFS 2010 and MS Project 2010 refresh work item issue

Tags: tfs, ms-project

When choosing which work items to import (through the Get Work Items option) to my newly created MS Project file I've accidentally checked a work item that shouldn't be imported.

I've removed this work item from my project file, but every time I click "Refresh" the work item appears again???

Is this the correct behavior? I can NEVER bring a work item and later decide to remove it from the project file without it coming back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to publish the entire Project file (Team -> Publish) without canceling the operation? I've experienced that. For some unknown reason, the TFS plugin does not save the query information in the project file when some error occurrs, even when publishing some WorkItems got suceeded.